# PyWinAuto How to set focus on a pop-up error message after a failed login

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to automate a Windows application login test to detect connectivity issue.

When the login attempt fails, the application returns a pop-up. My script (see below) will only continue to the 'try' block AFTER I click on the OK button in the pop-up.

My plan is to retrieve the error message on the pop-up and send an email alert.

Would appreciate some pointers. I'm totally new to pywinauto and I have not found anything in the documentation.

Thank you very much.

The script:

```
from pywinauto import application
import time
app = application.Application(backend="uia")
app.start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\Medxxxc.exe", wait_for_idle=False)

main_win = app.window(title='Medxxxc')
#main_win_wrapper = main_win.set_focus() 
#sign_in = main_win.child_window(title="Sign in", depth=2)
#sign_in = main_win.child_window(title="Connect to a Database", auto_id="DBConnect", control_type="Window")
sign_in = main_win.child_window(title="Connect to a Database", depth=3)

cnxnstring = sign_in.child_window(title="Connection:", auto_id="cboConnections", control_type="ComboBox")
username   = sign_in.child_window(title="User Name:",  auto_id="txtUserName",    control_type="Edit")
password   = sign_in.child_window(title="Password:",   auto_id="txtPassword",    control_type="Edit")
connect    = sign_in.child_window(title="Connect",     auto_id="cmdConnect",     control_type="Button")

cnxnstring.select("Rexxxing")
username.iface_value.SetValue("myusername") 
password.iface_value.SetValue("dummypasswd")
connect.click()

try:
    sign_in_error = main_win.child_window(title="OK", depth=4)
    print("sign-in error")
    sign_in_error.print_control_identifiers()
except Exception as e:
    print("%s" % e)
```

Here is what I see from the CMD prompt after I click on OK in the pop-up:

```
(venv32) c:\venv32\Scripts>python c:\test\check_myapp.py
sign-in error
{'title': 'OK', 'depth': 4, 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'MediTxxc', WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.1517e87_r9_ad1, 332134>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

Here is the error msg pop-up I'm trying to set focus to:
[image]

And here is the top portion of the identifiers:

```
Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'MediTxxc'    (L408, T141, R1353, B775)
['MediTxxc', 'MediTxxcDialog', 'Dialog', 'Dialog0', 'Dialog1']
child_window(title="MediTxxc", auto_id="MDIForm", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Dialog - 'Connect to a Database'    (L666, T366, R1095, B549)
   | ['Connect to a DatabaseDialog', 'Connect to a Database', 'Dialog2']
   | child_window(title="Connect to a Database", auto_id="DBConnect", control_type="Window")
   |    | 
   |    | Dialog - 'MediTxxc'    (L830, T471, R1106, B630)
   |    | ['MediTxxcDialog', 'MediTxxc', 'Dialog3']
   |    | child_window(title="MediTxxc", control_type="Window")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Button - 'OK'    (L1008, T590, R1083, B613)
   |    |    | ['Button', 'OKButton', 'OK', 'Button0', 'Button1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="OK", auto_id="2", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Image - ''    (L859, T525, R891, B557)
   |    |    | ['Image', 'Password:Image']
   |    |    | child_window(auto_id="20", control_type="Image")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - 'Login failed for user 'sxxxxxxa'.'    (L900, T535, R1068, B550)
   |    |    | ['Static', "Login failed for user 'sxxxxxxa'.Static", "Login failed for user 'sxxxxxxa'.", 'Static0', 'Static1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Login failed for user 'sxxxxxxa'.", auto_id="65535", control_type="Text")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | TitleBar - ''    (L838, T474, R1098, B502)
   |    |    | ['TitleBar', 'User Name:TitleBar', 'TitleBar0', 'TitleBar1']
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Button - 'Close'    (L1065, T472, R1099, B502)
   |    |    |    | ['Close', 'CloseButton', 'Button2', 'Close0', 'Close1', 'CloseButton0', 'CloseButton1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Close", control_type="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | GroupBox - 'Connection Information'    (L688, T411, R1073, B527)
   |    | ['Connection InformationGroupBox', 'GroupBox', 'Connection Information']
   |    | child_window(title="Connection Information", auto_id="frmConInfo", control_type="Group")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Edit - 'User Name:'    (L787, T465, R962, B485)
   |    |    | ['User Name:Edit', 'Edit', 'Edit0', 'Edit1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="User Name:", auto_id="txtUserName", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Button - 'Cancel'    (L979, T463, R1064, B488)
   |    |    | ['CancelButton', 'Button3', 'Cancel']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Cancel", auto_id="cmdCancel", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Edit - 'Password:'    (L787, T495, R962, B515)
   |    |    | ['Edit2', 'Password:Edit']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Password:", auto_id="txtPassword", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Button - 'Connect'    (L979, T430, R1064, B455)
   |    |    | ['Button4', 'ConnectButton', 'Connect']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Connect", auto_id="cmdConnect", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | ComboBox - 'Connection:'    (L787, T430, R962, B452)
   |    |    | ['Connection:ComboBox', 'Connection:', 'ComboBox', 'Connection:0', 'Connection:1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Connection:", auto_id="cboConnections", control_type="ComboBox")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Static - 'Connection:'    (L3, T3, R155, B19)
   |    |    |    | ['Static2', 'Connection:2', 'Connection:Static', 'Connection:Static0', 'Connection:Static1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Connection:", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Button - 'Open'    (L946, T431, R961, B451)
   |    |    |    | ['OpenButton', 'Button5', 'Open']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Open", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - 'User Name:'    (L711, T468, R781, B482)
   |    |    | ['User Name:Static', 'Static3', 'User Name:']
   |    |    | child_window(title="User Name:", auto_id="lblUserName", control_type="Text")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - 'Password:'    (L715, T498, R781, B512)
   |    |    | ['Static4', 'Password:Static', 'Password:', 'Password:Static0', 'Password:Static1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Password:", auto_id="lblPassword", control_type="Text")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - 'Connection:'    (L708, T438, R781, B452)
   |    |    | ['Static5', 'Connection:3', 'Connection:Static2']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Connection:", auto_id="lblServer", control_type="Text")
```

And

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue. I changed this line

```
   connect.click()
```

to

```
   connect.click_input()
```

Now the script proceeds to the OK button in the pop-up.

Thank you.